# GetLastInputInfo API doesn't work if windows is set to "Automatic Login"

Tags: c#, winapi

I use a Windows API call to **[GetLastInputInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo)** to determine if the system is idle. This works in pretty much any scenario - except when Windows is set to bypass the username/password and login automatically.

In this case, querying [**GetLastInputInfo**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo) always returns `0`. In normal conditions, it would return the system tick count when the last input occurred.

Does anyone know why? Or does anyone know an alternate method to determine if a windows session is idle?

### Edit

This is how the code is written to detect the current system idle time. The detection occurs on a timer and regardless of how long the timer runs, GetLastInputInfo will always return 0 while windows is set to "auto login".

```
long lastInputTicks = 0;
long idleTicks = 0;

LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
lastInputInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);
lastInputInfo.dwTime = 0;

if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo)) {
   lastInputTicks = lastInputInfo.dwTime;

   var systemUptime = GetTickCount();

   idleTicks = systemUptime - lastInputTicks;
}

return new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)(idleTicks / 1000));
```

Thanks

### Update

I've confirmed that this only happens because the code runs in a service.

To clarify: Under a normal scenario where auto-login is not being used, the user logs in at the console and the above code -- even if running as a service -- will return the proper user inactivity time.

However, if auto-login is turned on, then the windows session appears to not run as a typical console session, and is therefore **NOT** tracked. This applies only when the code is ran from a service and not from the "user space" - it works great in all cases if running from a user space.

That said, I'd really love to find a solution that works *from a service* in every scenario.

Comment: Is this right after login?  Was there any actual input?  Do you check the function return value?  A code snippet would have avoided some of this guessing.

Comment: @Hans - Yes, input can be constant and the api will still always show 0. It works fine when auto-login is disabled (it feels like a Windows but of some sort)

Comment: Hmm, this code isn't actually doing anything useful when it returns FALSE.  Rarely a coincidence.

Comment: Is there something special about the context in which this code runs? For example, is it in a service or other atypical code context? How does this app get started? Did the user start it from the start menu, or is it started somehow else?

Comment: It runs as a service. Are services treated different from an auto-login perspective?

Comment: @Hans I'm not sure I follow. It doesn't return FALSE, it returns a TimeSpan representing how long the pc has been in an idle state.

Comment: @bugfixr did you actually find a way to tell idle time from a service?

Comment: @bugfixr Did you find a solution to monitor user activity from the service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It returns 0 seconds when GetLastInput() returns FALSE.  Which is obviously incorrect.  You cannot use code like this in a service, it doesn't have a way to retrieve user input.  If GetLastInput() ever returns FALSE (likely with auto-login) then it will return FALSE forever.

Having services be aware of user sessions is a lost cause in Windows, a service runs in its own session and doesn't need a user to be logged-in.  Which is the major reason to use a service in the first place.  Instead of a program that's started with, say, a shortcut in the Startup folder.  This code might have worked by accident in XP but it definitely won't work in Vista and Windows 7.  Google "session 0 isolation" for more details.

Comment: It actually DOES work in Vista/Windows 7 as long as auto-login is not being used.

Answer (score 1):

The [**Remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo#remarks) section of the documentation pretty much explains why it won't work:

> This function is useful for input idle detection. However, GetLastInputInfo does not provide system-wide user input information across all running sessions. Rather, GetLastInputInfo provides **session-specific user input information for only the session that invoked the function.**

So that's that.

Comment: Yup. Leave it to Microsoft to provide a technically-correct answer without really being helpful.

Comment: @Suncat2000 Well i'm sure i know exactly why: you don't want one user spying on another: you're only allowed to see your own activity.