# Cant Get PC Idle Time

Tags: c#

I found a [Tutorial](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial210_Retrieving-the-Operating-System-Idle-Time-Uptime-and-Last-Input-Time.html) on how to get the idle time of PC. how ever when i run the sample the idle time is always 0 no matter how idle i leave my pc!

the system Up-time is working good but the  Idle Time is always 0! any idea why this is happening ?

- Windows 7 64bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Windows Decides to show the screensave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970625/how-windows-decides-to-show-the-screensave)

Comment: @HansPassant im not asking how to get IdleTime im asking why that code is not working ! the question your pointing to is discussing a different issue and with totaly different code!

Answer (score 0):

I'm in danger of telling you what you probably already know, but that code is for user idle time rather than system idle time.

Using Environment.TickCount is a questionable practice as the value starts at 0, goes up to X (after about 25 days) and then wraps round to -X. So you can't always use straight subtraction as the code suggests.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.80).aspx

Given that you're on running it on a PC though, this should be fine (assuming you reboot fairly regularly).

Depending on how you're running it, you may also want to have a look at this:

[GetLastInputInfo API doesn't work if windows is set to "Automatic Login"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146114/getlastinputinfo-api-doesnt-work-if-windows-is-set-to-automatic-login)

Comment: Yeah my windows is not set to Automatic Login and i know the issue with Environment.tickcount but still i cant get it to return anything but 0 :S

Comment: Very strange - I take it you're running this in a GUI as the tutorial describes and not wrapping it in a service?

Comment: yes just the same GUI ! could it be because im on windows 7 64 bit ?

Comment: Could be...what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Works fine on XP pro with a VS2005 build. I'll see if it plays on my Windows 7 64-bit later.

Comment: i dont think its the VS as i just run it without VS i mean by opening the exe itself

Comment: Was just curious. If I get the same issue on my Win 7 64 bit machine I was going to try building it in VS2010.

Comment: i dont really think vs has anything to do with the code working or not, i have been searching the web about this issue for 2 hours...

Comment: If I were to take a punt, I'd say it was the OS. They locked down loads of this sort of stuff starting with Vista.

Comment: Could be something to do with it using unmanaged code too. Maybe try building it as bona fide 64-bit app rather than the default (Any CPU).

Comment: didnt make any different building it to 64 or 86 still dwTime return 0...!

Comment: OMG guess what ! turned out that its my Microsoft Wireless mouse that causes the dwTime to always reset to 0 ! if i unplug the USB Wireless mouse it works ! now i wonder if the problem with all the wireless mouses or just mine !

Comment: That would make sense. There are probably mouse events still being generated to make sure the battery isn't dead etc.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e3966da0-2a12-4722-bbe5-7d6543156364/